# Powershell: Openfile dialog and Set-Content Issue. Cannot access file. In use

Tags: powershell, openfiledialog

What I'm trying to do is utilize the openfile dialog, select an ini file and make line changes to it at the end of this script with set-content.  But I keep getting the error that Set-Content : The process cannot access the file, and that it's in use.

```
$a = $env:userprofile
Function Get-FileName($InitialDirectory)
{
Get-FileName -InitialDirectory "$a\AppData\Roaming\Milliman"
}#end function Get-FileName

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$dialog.DefaultExt = '.*'
$dialog.Filter = 'All Files|*.*'
$dialog.FilterIndex = 0
$dialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
$dialog.Multiselect = $false
$dialog.RestoreDirectory = $true
$dialog.Title = "Select a file"
$dialog.ValidateNames = $true
$dialog.ShowHelp = $true
$dialog.ShowDialog()
$dialog.FileName


##Folder Dialog
$dir = new-object -com Shell.Application
$aldir = $dir.BrowseForFolder(0, "AL Dir", 0, "C:\Program Files\Milliman\")
if ($aldir.Self.Path -ne "") {write-host "You selected " $aldir.Self.Path}


## Grid Integration Steps

Copy-Item -path "\\ap102aric\alfaadmin$\Ver70andAbove\DataSynapse\*" -destination "C:\Program     Files\Common Files\Milliman\MG-ALFA Shared\DataSynapse" -Force

Copy-Item -path "\\ap102aric\alfaadmin$\Ver70andAbove\JobOptions-RPRic\*"  -destination "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Milliman\MG-ALFA Shared\DataSynapse" -Force

Copy-Item -path "\\ap102aric\alfaadmin$\Ver70andAbove\GSDLL\dsdrv.dll" -Destination $aldir.Self.Path -Force


## Set Environment Variable
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DSDRIVER_DIR","C:\Program Files\Common Files\Milliman\MG-ALFA Shared\DataSynapse\Config","Machine")

## Edit Config UI.ini to set SDP LOGON for Datasynapse
#Write-Host $dialog.FileName
Get-Content $dialog.FileName | ForEach-Object {
$_ -replace 'SDPAvailable=*','SDPAvailable=DataSynapse'
   -replace 'SDPFolder=*','SDPFolder=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Milliman\MG-ALFA Shared\DataSynapse'
   -replace 'SDPLogon=*','SDPAvailable=Yes'
 } | Set-Content $dialog.FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try destroying the `$aldir` object.  It may be holding a handle to the file.  I'm not sure how to do that.  Maybe set it to $null after you grab the path the user selected.

You can also try using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out what process is locking the file.

Finally, you can't pipe the output from `Get-Content` to `Set-Content`, e.g.

```
Get-Content $Path | Set-Content $Path
```

Items are sent down the PowerShell pipeline immediately, so when `Get-Content` reads a line, it immediately gets set to `Set-Content`, which won't work because `Get-Content` has the file open.  Instead, try saving the contents of the file:

```
$file = Get-Content $path
# Modify $file
$file | Set-Content $path
```